# SQLGrammarException with Hibernate and Oracle11g

Tags: oracle, hibernate, oracle11g

Two problems -
If I query an entity, I get...

```
ERROR: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Nov 11, 2013 8:47:36 PM org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener onLoad
INFO: HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

If I try to insert an entity, I get...

```
Hibernate: insert into MyDB.dbo.BOSS_CONTACTS_C_LVL (CNTCT_PHN_NBR, CVM_CNTCT_EMAIL, DTID, BUSINESS_NAME, CONTACT_NAME, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, PHONE_NUMBER, CONTACT_TITLE, EMPLOYEES_HERE, REGION, AREA, BRANCH_NAME, BRANCH_ID, IN_OUTBOUND, PROSPECT_TYPE, RATING, DUNS_NUMBER, ADDRESS, CITY, STATE, ZIP, LOCAL_STREET, LOCAL_CITY, LOCAL_STATE_PROVINCE, LOCAL_ZIP_POSTAL_CODE, HANDSET_POTENTIAL, CAMPAIGN_NAME, CAMPAIGN_CODE, ASSIGNED_REP, TOTAL_TELECOM, PROFILE_ID, BUSINESS_ID, KEYCODE, SIC, CVM_UNQ_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Nov 11, 2013 9:00:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 926, SQLState: 42000
Nov 11, 2013 9:00:53 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword
```

I've tried several different Oracle drivers thinking that could be the problem.
I also read a post somewhere that one of the field names could be an Oracle keyword, but I removed all fields but the primary key to test and the error still occurs.

hibernate.cfg -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
                                         "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
  <property name="show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">oasisd_02</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@MyServer:1521/MyDB</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_catalog">MyDB</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">dbo</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
  <mapping class="myPrj.domain.Contact" resource="myPrj/domain/Contact.hbm.xml"/>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The mapping file is generated from JBOSS Tools in Eclipse.

Also, I've tried JDK 1.6 and 1.7

*Updated* - 
I should add that I am not using a custom HQL query.

Using a repository pattern -

```
public class ContactRepository implements IContactRepository {

    public Contact find(String cvmUnqId) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Contact aContact = (Contact) session.load(Contact.class, cvmUnqId);
        return aContact;
    }

    public Contact findByZipCode(String zipcode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public void store(Contact contact) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(contact);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void remove(Contact contact)
    {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(contact);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

And the test case -

```
@Test
public void testContactList(){
    ContactRepository contactRepo = new ContactRepository();
    Object result = contactRepo.find("FakeID");
    assertEquals(result, null);
}

@Test
public void addRemoveContactTest() {
    ContactRepository contactRepo = new ContactRepository();

    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.setAddress("123 Anywhere");
    contact.setArea('A');
    contact.setAssignedRep('B');
    contact.setBranchId('C');
    contact.setBranchName('D');
    contact.setBusinessId("Business ID");
    contact.setBusinessName("Fake Business");
    contact.setZip("11111");
    contact.setCvmUnqId("FakeID");
    contactRepo.store(contact);

    Contact foundContact = contactRepo.find(contact.getCvmUnqId());
    assertEquals("Contact was not found in repository", contact, foundContact);

    contactRepo.remove(contact);
    foundContact = contactRepo.find(contact.getCvmUnqId());
    assertEquals("Contact was not removed from repository", null, foundContact);
}
```

And the factory utility in case thats relevant -

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = configureSessionFactory();
    private static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    private static SessionFactory configureSessionFactory() throws HibernateException {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Issue solved.
The multi-part table identifier was incorrect. I removed the default catalog property from the hibernate configuration and it works fine now.
I’m surprised it wasn’t a better error message from Oracle. Something like “table doesn’t exist”…

Comment: SQLGrammarException - Mostly due to invalid sql. Check the query string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved.
The multi-part table identifier was incorrect. I removed the default catalog property from the hibernate configuration and it works fine now.
I’m surprised it wasn't a better error message from Oracle. Something like “table doesn't exist”…

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to figure out which statement is causing the oracle errors is to connect a session to the database and turn on sql tracing or enable event 10046 trace.

to turn on tracing, use
  alter session set sql_trace=true

to turn on 10046 tracing one
  alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever, level 12';

10046 can also be turned by the dba for other database sessions.

Then start the workload and analyze the corresponding trace file. The trace files are created in the directory specified by the init.ora parameter user_dump_dest.